# If $L^2$ is regular. Does that imply L is regular

Tags: automata, regular-languages

If $L^2$ is regular. Does that imply L is regular.

---

I think L need not be regular. But I can't find any example where L is not regular but $L^2$ is regular.

My teacher told me an example where L={$0^k$ | k is composite} clearly L is not regular. But he claims that $L^2$ is regular. I don't know why it is regular? Please help.

Comment: Your teacher gave good example. You should just write out some words in $L^2$ to see what $L^2$ is actually equivalent to. That's the hint.

Comment: I added an answer to the other question, explaining why your teacher's claim is true.